# arguing away - complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, estimation

Probably a trivial question but I can't understand how to argue away the value of integrals in complex analysis.
I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)=\frac{1}{s(s+1)}$. The integral I therefore have to compute is $f(t)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{c+i\infty}_{c-i\infty}\dfrac{e^{st}}{s(s+1)}ds$ and I'm using the 'Bromwich contour'.
I have to 'argue away' the contribution from the semi-circular arc of the 'Bromwich contour' but I don't understand the method of how to do so.$$|\int_c|\leq2\pi R.max\dfrac{e^{st}}{s(s+1)}$$
any help in understanding the method would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** On the arc and assuming $t>0$, $|e^{st}|\leq e^{ct}$ and $\max \left|s^{-1}(s+1)^{-1}\right| \sim R^{-2}$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: Have I understood your question correctly?

Comment: How does one get $s^{-1}(s+1)^{-1}$ to $O(R^{-2})$? Am I right in saying that by the estimation lemma, we have $|\int_c|\leq \dfrac{\pi Re^{ct}}{R^2-R}$ which approaches zero as R goes to $\infty$?

Comment: @L.oiler, Yes, definitely (don't forget the $2$ :) ).  The asymptotic argument is similar.  Write $s^{-1}(s+1)^{-1} = s^{-2}(1+s^{-1})^{-1}$.  Then, on the arc, you have $|s| = R$, so $$\max |s^{-2}(1+s^{-1})^{-1}| = R^{-2} \max |1+s^{-1}|^{-1} = R^{-2}|1+\hat{s}(R)^{-1}|^{-1},$$ where $\hat{s}(R)$ maximizes the expression $|1+s^{-1}|^{-1}$ on the arc for a given $R$.  But $|\hat{s}(R)|=R$, so $1+\hat{s}(R)^{-1} \to 1$ as $R \to \infty$.